# Find and Replace on a particular column

Tags: awk, sed, solaris, cut

I like to find and replace on the specific column using `sed`, because I don't know why `awk` `gsub()` didn't work in my Unix (Solaris) that's why I want to use `sed`.

Sample Data:

```
122|abc|ds,we||wrqg
145|dw|ett,335||nxd
166|rotl|qqqp,eoepepe||ge
776|gge|022||pp
039|pot|011a||lot
```

On the 3rd column, I want to replace comma(`,`) in pipe(`|`)

When I'm try to use `gsub()`, there's an error:

```
awk '{gsub(",","|",$3)}1' in.file > out.file

awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

Another, I will import it on my database(Oracle). If the data with `,` will be replace with `|`, the data records that changed will not be on the same field. How can it be done?

The output should be like this.

```
122|abc|ds|we|wrqg
145|dw|ett|335|nxd
166|rotl|qqqp|eoepepe|ge
776|gge|022||pp
039|pot|011a||lot
```

Anyone, I really need this.

Comment: Need your help guys.

Comment: I don't get that error. It just doesn't work because you don't set the `FS` and `OFS` to `|`.

Comment: You're running on Solaris?

Comment: I'm using putty.@Kusalananda

Comment: `putty` is an ssh client. What is the OS on the server side?

Comment: Server side? I used portable putty on my Windows10.

Comment: Windows10+putty is the *client* side. What is the server OS. Use command `uname -a` to find out.

Comment: What Unix are you running `awk` on?  What does `uname -a` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/usr/bin/awk` on Solaris is severely limited in its support for various functions.  In particular, the `gsub()` function is not implemented.  This is explained in [the manual for `awk` on Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/awk-1.html#scrolltoc).

For that, you should use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (or `nawk`, "new `awk`").

Your code also don't specify a field separator for `awk`, so `$3` would never contain anything unless you happen to have enough whitespace in your data to accidentally create a 3rd whitespace separated field.  Likewise, you don't specify the output field separator, so any modified lines would have its fields delimited by spaces.

Instead:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(",", "|", $3); print }' file
```

To always get `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` as your default `awk` on Solaris, use `PATH="$(/usr/xpg4/bin/getconf PATH):$PATH"` in your shell's startup file.

Comment: The code works! What if I set as my default `awk`, does my `awk` that I'm using on my server will affect the other function of awk? Or its the same and upgraded?

Comment: @Ace It is conceivable that you actually _always_ want to use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and _never_ `/usr/bin/awk`, as the older implementation of `awk` on Solaris is severely lacking.  If you ever used `awk` on another Unix, the XPG4 `awk` will be the one that behaves most like most other `awk` implementations.

Comment: I still another problem. There are data that don't have a `,`. The problem is I will import it on my database, so the data will not match on the field. How it will be done?

Comment: @Ace I would suggest that you ask a new question about this. I'm a bit busy at the moment and there are many others that knows this stuff as well as (and better than!) me.

Comment: Thanks a lot J!